# Python: using a variable in Counter().most_common(x)

Tags: python-3.x, counter

I want to use a variable as an argument for count = Counter(list).most_common(x). But receive this error: 
TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int()

My code works fine when there is a constant in place for x like: count = Counter(list).most_common(2)

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: what is `type(x)`? (it should be an integer)

Comment: it is an integer. It was taken as a command line argument

Comment: **what is `type(x)`?**

Comment: O sorry, I see now. It says it is a string. Thanks for pointing this out! adding int(x) fixes it. Thanks again!